# dynamic href url based on ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic, href

Really not sure how to even go about asking this question but it is something like this.

How can I run some type of ajax(php script on server end) based on user's onclick action and dynamically launch url based on return from ajax and put it in href effectively launching that url?

so I want to say something like

```
enter code here

<a href="urlYetTobeDeterminedAtTheTimeOfOnClick" onclick=sometfunctionWhichREturnsUrl>
```

And say I have a php function which returns site:a.com if it's before midnight to 8am, site:b.com if it's 8am to noon and site:c.com if it's noon to midnight. I don't need a exact code but some sort of direction of how this can be arranged.. I have done lot of research on google but I do not see anything so far that I can use or point me to right direction. Can someone please advise?

thank you.

Comment: Well have you tried anything yourself so far?

Comment: I tried many different searches but no luck.   Frankly i can handle onclick function but not sure what to put in href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just have the anchor point to the a url that determines the address to go to and then let it call a redirect to the url.

```
<a href="script.php">
```

script.php

```
<?php
$url = get_the_url_function();
header('Location: '.$url);
exit;
```

Comment: Sorry this did not work.  It just launches into php page

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't put anything in the href.
You will do an ajax request to the endpoint responsible for the business logic behind deciding where to send the user.

That endpoint will return a json object which includes a value that has the url to send the user to. You will check for a successful response, if success then window.location({insert value here});